# Getting NaN and infinity value in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssms

Here is my formula

Deviation=(Today- yesterday)/yesterday

Need the value in %

1. If today is 0, then the value should be -100%(negative deviation)
2. If yesterday is 0, then the value should be +100%(positive deviation)

Issue:

1.Getting NaN if both today and yesterday are 0. Expected -100%

2.And infinity if yesterday is zero. Expected +100%

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your expression looks like that below

```
= (Fields!myvalue.Value-Previous(Fields!myvalue.Value)) / Previous(Fields!myvalue.Value)
```

You can use switch to customize the output based on conditions when current or previous value is 0

Adjust your expression to look like that below

```
= Switch(
Fields!myvalue.Value=0 AND Previous(Fields!myvalue.Value)=0, -1,
Previous(Fields!myvalue.Value)=0, 1,
True, (Fields!myvalue.Value-Previous(Fields!myvalue.Value)) / Previous(Fields!myvalue.Value)
)
```

[image]